# Clicking a button and having message output and new page opened based on set values in check b

Tags: javascript

I have 4 drop down lists on my page. Im trying to output a message and then open up a new page on the click of a submit button. This is based on the condition of a single value of each drop down list being true. all the options of each check list being true. For example 50p=true, in the next box £2 equals true and so on for each list.

Here is an example of one of the boxes. The other 3 boxes have the exact same names but just have different true and false values

```
<input name="button" type="submit" class="main" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" />

<select name="select_box" size="1" class="main" id="select_box">
<option value="true">50p</option>
<option value="false">1p</option>
<option value="false" selected="selected">20p</option>
<option value="false">£2</option>
</select>
```

This is where ive had an attempt at trying to assign variables. My logic was if i could assign variables to the names of the drop down lists by getting their id i could apply an if statement that would give me the desired outcome based on the onclick function, as the select boxes have true and false values in them ? When i run this code Javascript only seems to acknowledge and call up the alert box regardless of the options, its as if there is no other code there.

```
var a=document.getElementById("select_box");
var b=document.getElementById("select_box2");
var c=document.getElementById("select_box3");
var d=document.getElementById("select_box4");

object.onclick=submit
if (a=true,b=true,c=true,d=true)
{
alert("Correct you have won press OK for your Reward!")
document.open("Reward.html");
}
else
{
alert("Not right Please try again!");
}
```

Also how do I apply the above mentioned submit button to work these statements

I apologise for the poor editing at the top of the first half of the code im not too sure how to editi it so the rest of the words show

Answer (score 0):

In your code `a` is holding the actual select element, when you really want it to hold the current **value** of the select element.  So change

```
var a = document.getElementById("select_box");
```

to this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("select_box").value;
```

This will assign `a` to be the **value** of the dropdown in question.  Just make sure you fix your comparison:

```
if (a=true
```

should be

```
if (a === 'true'
```

---

Also note that setting the value of your dropdown's values to just true or false

```
<option value="true">50p</option>
<option value="false">1p</option>
<option value="false" selected="selected">20p</option>
<option value="false">£2</option>
```

will make it hard for your server side code to process what the user actually chose, since the only value that'll come over for that form input will be a true, or false, and if false, you'll have no way of knowing which of those three false values were actually chosen.

Comment: I assinged .value at the end of each variable and changed my if statement. Javascript accecpts the code but nothing happens when ran  <script type="javascript">
var a = document.getElementById("select_box").value
var b = document.getElementById("select_box2").value;
var c = document.getElementById("select_box3").value;
var d = document.getElementById("select_box4").value
 if(a == 'true' && b == 'true' && c == 'true' && d == 'true')
  {
  alert("Correct you have won press OK for your Reward!");
   document.open("Reward.html");
 }
 else
  {
  alert("Not right Please try again!");
  } 
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

First, to get the value of a select box, you need to do this:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("select_box");
var a = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
```

Next, for your if-statement, a few things are wrong. First, you are using a single equals sign instead of a double equals to compare. You are also comparing them with boolean values, when the values returned by your select box are strings. Finally, you cannot separate conditionals with a comma. You must specify AND or OR or something. Change your if-statement so something more like this:

```
if (a == "true" && b == "true" && c == "true" && d == "true")
```

---

**UPDATE:** Here is an example of what I think you're trying to do:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function submit()
        {
            // fill these in with the values for the correct answers
            var correctAnswers = new Array("50p", "50p", "50p", "50p");
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                // if any of the values turn up incorrect, stop right there and go back. No need to check the rest of the values.
                if (document.getElementById("select_box"+ i).options[document.getElementById("select_box"+ i).selectedIndex].value != correctAnswers[i-1])
                {
                    alert("Not right, please try again!");
                    return;
                }
            }

            alert("Corect, you have won! Press OK for your reward!");
            document.getElementById("frmMainForm").submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Reward.html" method="post" id="frmMainForm">
        <select name="select_box1" size="1" class="main" id="select_box">
            <option value="50p">50p</option>    <!-- use the actual value, not "true" or "false" -->
            <option value="1p">1p</option>
            <option value="20p" selected="selected">20p</option>
            <option value="£2">£2</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select_box2" size="1" class="main" id="select_box">
            <option value="50p">50p</option>
            <option value="1p">1p</option>
            <option value="20p" selected="selected">20p</option>
            <option value="£2">£2</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select_box3" size="1" class="main" id="select_box">
            <option value="50p">50p</option>
            <option value="1p">1p</option>
            <option value="20p" selected="selected">20p</option>
            <option value="£2">£2</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select_box4" size="1" class="main" id="select_box">
            <option value="50p">50p</option>
            <option value="1p">1p</option>
            <option value="20p" selected="selected">20p</option>
            <option value="£2">£2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="main" id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit()" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure how important this is, but keep in mind that anybody that views your source code from their browser window can get the correct answers. If this is a problem for your, then you should have your form submit to a server-side (e.g. PHP, ASP, JSP, etc.) script to check the values for you.

Comment: Ive treid this method and nothing happens i applied this method to each select box like you suggested like this var selectbox = document.getElementById("select_box"); 
var a = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;
var selectbox2 = document.getElementById("select_box2"); 
var b = selectbox2.options[selectbox2.selectedIndex].value;                                                   I then apply the if statement like you said, run the code and nothing happens, is it to do with where my script tags and stuff are ? or perhaps i need to assign it to a button in which i dont know how to

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` for an  can be anything, the proper usage would be `<option value="50p">50p</option>` then, when you use

```
if(document.getElementById('select_box').value == '50p') {
    alert('50p was selected');
}
```

this will work